# Recreating same transform on UIImageView after pan/resize/rotate

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I have a problem which is causing me a 'headache' and hope someone out there can help me.

I have a UIView with a child UIImageView presented on top, containing an image.

Using gestures, I can pan, scale and rotate that image. During this process, the anchor point may change to ensure the scale/rotate is point between the two fingers of the gesture. CGAffineTransforms are used to achieve this and it works well.

My problem is storing and recreating the transforms when I destroy and recreate the enclosing view controller.

When I leave that view, I store the transform and frame...

```
-(CGAffineTransform)imageViewTransform
{
    return self.testImageView.transform;
}

-(CGRect)imageViewFrame
{
    return self.testImageView.frame;
}
```

....and when I recreate that view I set the frame and transform of my imageView...

```
self.imageView.transform = mySavedTransform;
self.imageView.frame = mySavedFrame;
```

This works and I can move and stretch my image, then recreate next time in.

However, if I rotate my image, the recreated image frame at the correct angle but is stretched and not at original coordinates, so I don't get exactly what I saved.

Setting the frame before the transform has the same undesired effect on rotations.

My question is why can't I recreate the exact scaled, rotated and positioned UIImageView using the above technique?

Surely reproducing the frame and transform would have the desired effect?

Is this the usual method for doing this, or am I missing something?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For those interest, this is sorted.

The problem was the anchor-point which was not being stored, as well as using the center for recreation of the image. So, to faithfully reproduce a transformation, it appears you need to store the center, transform and anchor.

HTH